# EqualityComparer is missing?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

[image]

Ive seen example of :

```
  int[] a1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
  int[] b1 = { 1, 2, 3 };

a1.Equals(b1) //false

a1.Equals(b1,EqualityComparer<int>.Default)); //true
```

However I cant get the overloaded method as you see...

what am i missing ?

Comment: Where have you seen such example? There's no such overload (the second) in the BCL unless someone defined it as a custom extension method.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov see the middle example : http://books.google.co.il/books?id=VENrFSQFco8C&pg=PA310&lpg=PA310&dq=%22+istructuralEquatable+and+IstructuralComparable%22&source=bl&ots=3uT3jocWfQ&sig=71JlpQNYpBPJYTzQbo-hjbkUMDM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vhobT6K3NYKe-wb3_tioCg&ved=0CEEQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22%20istructuralEquatable%20and%20IstructuralComparable%22&f=false

Comment: That overload looks like `IStructuralEquatable`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such method on `System.Object`(or any other type that would allow such use on an array of ints).
I think you're looking for [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073.aspx) method, an extension-method from LINQ to Objects:

```
a1.SequenceEqual(b1, EqualityComparer<int>.Default)
```

although you might as well equivalently do:

```
a1.SequenceEqual(b1)
```

EDIT: If you want to use the `Equals` method from `IStructuralEquatable`, you'll have to cast to the interface since arrays [implement this interface explictly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783207.aspx):

```
((IStructuralEquatable)a1).Equals(b1, EqualityComparer<int>.Default)
```

Comment: see the middle example http://books.google.co.il/books?id=VENrFSQFco8C&pg=PA310&lpg=PA310&dq=%22+istructuralEquatable+and+IstructuralComparable%22&source=bl&ots=3uT3jocWfQ&sig=71JlpQNYpBPJYTzQbo-hjbkUMDM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vhobT6K3NYKe-wb3_tioCg&ved=0CEEQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22%20istructuralEquatable%20and%20IstructuralComparable%22&f=false

Comment: @Royi: Because the interface is [implemented explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx). If you had done `IStructuralEquatable a1 = new[]{ 1, 2, 3 };`, it would have worked directly.

Comment: I understand that , but why the code from the book is printed that away  , without (!) the interface ?

Comment: @Royi: It's definitely a mistake - that won't compile.

Comment: Ive wrote them  Guess its a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

The overloaded method you're reffering to, is an extension method.  Intellisense will only show it, when you declare the namespace where the method is declared in, in your usings block.

However, the method is called `SequenceEqual`, and not just Equals.
The method you'd want, is declared in `System.Linq`.

```
using System.Linq;

...

a1.SequenceEqual (b1, EqualityComparer<int>.Default);
```

Comment: @w0lf you can see that the error is not it. (although you right) the resharper doesnt tell me nothing

Comment: @RoyiNamir the name of the method is `SequenceEqual` (without the final *s*), as @Ani pointed out in his answer

Comment: @w0lf oh im sorry . let me check :)

Comment: @Frederik can you see the http://books.google.co.il/books?id=VENrFSQFco8C&pg=PA310&lpg=PA310&dq=%22+istructuralEquatable+and+IstructuralComparable%22&source=bl&ots=3uT3jocWfQ&sig=71JlpQNYpBPJYTzQbo-hjbkUMDM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vhobT6K3NYKe-wb3_tioCg&ved=0CEEQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22%20istructuralEquatable%20and%20IstructuralComparable%22&f=false the middle example ? why cant i write it like them ?